# Trying to triple boot iMac

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, macintosh, parrotsec

Recently I installed Parrot Security OS Home 3.11 on a late 2006 iMac5,2 (OS X 10.6.8, 2.5GB RAM, 2.33GHz Intel Core 2 Duo) which already had a bootcamp partition running Windows 7 Professional x86. After installing Parrot OS, Windows no longer boots, giving the error "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key".

I have learned that this is due to EFI/hybrid MBR and followed the instructions listed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/650194/repair-windows-boot-loader-after-installing-ubuntu-on-macbook-pro exactly to replace the hybrid MBR with protective MBR, but that hasn't helped and Windows still will not boot.

Comment: Could you please share your partition layout before and after the install of Parrot OS?

Comment: Maybe converting the disk to GPT would help?

Comment: Before I had just the OS X partition (ext4, 213GB), the bootcamp partition (NTFS, 106GB), and a small recovery partition.

Comment: After installing Parrot, I have 5 total partitions: /dev/sda1 EFI system partition (fat32, 200MiB), /dev/sda2 OS X (HFS+, 99.31GB) [correction to above, OS X partition was not ext4], /dev/sda3 Parrot (ext4, 97.21GB), /dev/sda5 Linux-swap (linux-swap, 1.98GB), and /dev/sda4 Bootcamp (NTFS, 99.4GB). That is the order in gparted. Also, I installed the 32 bit Parrot OS if that makes any difference. How would I convert to GPT?

Comment: Read the following post: https://superuser.com/questions/495672/how-can-i-convert-a-mbr-partition-to-gpt-without-loss-of-data#495673.

Comment: It doesn't appear to have fixed the problem, I still can't get into Windows. When I run gdisk /dev/sda in the terminal I get "Partition table scan: MBR: protective BSD: not present APM: not present GPT: present" now